# How to deserialize in Java script

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

I have a string returned into js from a wrapper class  and want to desrialize and change to `list<string>` but not be to convert.
I have tried the below code .

`var listData = (list<string>)JSON.deserialize(result.data,list<string>.class);`

Comment: That code is a mix of Apex and JavaScript syntax and is not valid in either language. JavaScript doesn't have a type called `List<String>`. Please [edit] to clarify where you are working.

Comment: Ok , I have serialized data in Apex as . response.data = JSON.serialize(fieldSetApiNameList);

Comment: where response.data is of string..response.data = JSON.serialize(fieldSetApiNameList);
this data i have taken in Salesforce Lightning components JS
I want to desrialize this string in JS

Comment: The answers here about using `JSON.parse` are accurate, but why does the data need to be serialized as a JSON string in the first place? There is nothing wrong with returning a `List<String>`, which in Javascript is going to be an array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already have a serialized string in apex and in javascript you want o deserialize it:

From Apex : `JSON.serialize(you object);`

and in Javascript just do : `JSON.parse(variable from apex)`

If you have a reverse, say from JS you want to pass a serialized string to Apex the do this: 
From Javascript: `JSON.stringify(you object);`

and in Apex just do : `(list<string>)JSON.deserialize(Variable from Javascript,list<string>.class)`

Read `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` for more examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.parse(response.data) to construct JS object out of your string.